# Preparing my work laptop for returning

Tags: system-installation, delete, reset, cleanup

I want to give my work laptop back to my employer. It has Ubuntu installed on it. I would like to create a new admin user with a new password and delete my current user (the only one the system has) - all my data and my current password included. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Reinstalling is probably the easiest and fastest way to do that,

Comment: Check with your employer -- they might routinely wipe and re-image returned laptops anyway. I was with one organization that paid employees to watch the technician wipe their drive as part of their outprocessing, so there would be no misunderstandings or rumors about data leaks.

Comment: They have told me I need to do this. Yes, maybe reinstalling will be the best way ...

Comment: next time I suggest dong a clonezilla backup of all disks (or partitions) when you get it, then Clonezilla back to that when you return it. a wipe of empty space would be a good idea too.